# How to change a css declaration by the value of a selected drop down box option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code already that will hide the epcCatHide6 select box on page load, I would like it to only show the epcCatHide6 select box when epcCat[1] option 3 is selected..
This is what I have already,

```
<select name="epcCat[1]" class="formElements" id="category">
<option value="1">Blah</option>
<option value="3">Blah Blah</option>
<option value="4">Blah Blah Blah</option>
<option value="5">Etc</option>
<option value="180">Etc Etc</option>
</select>

<select name="epcCat[6]" class="formElements" id="category">
<option value="0">-----</option>
<option value="181">12</option>
<option value="182">11</option>
<option value="183">10</option>
</select>

<style type="text/css">.epcCatHide6 {display:none}</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.body).on('change','select[name="epcCat[1]"]',function(){
var newstyle = document.createElement("style");
newstyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(".epcCatHide6{display:block!important}"));
document.body.appendChild(newstyle);
});
</script>
```

How can I get this to work when only epcCat[1] option '3' is selected?
Many thanks for any advice offered.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `onchange` event to inject new style elements: you are basically injecting a new one every single time the dropdown is updated. What about simply using `document.querySelector(...)` to change the display property of the node's style object?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply use an `onchange` handler on the `<select>` of your choosing. Also, remember to keep your IDs unique.

```
var d = document;
var el = d.getElementsByName('epcCat[1]')[0];

el.onchange = function()
{
    if(el.value === '3')
    {
        var h = d.getElementsByClassName('epcCatHide6');

        for(var i = 0; i < h.length; i++)
        {
            h[i].style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope your app already contain jQuery library

```
$('body').on('change','[name="epcCat[1]"]',function(){
        val = $(this).val();
        if(val =="3"){ console.log('its three'); $('.epcCatHide6').show();  }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "Don't".
Don't change the CSS declaration, instead you can add and remove *additional* classes which can affect visibility, leaving the `.epcCatHide6` CSS declaration alone.

But even easier, since you are already using jQuery, you can use its [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) methods.

First, though, you have to fix your HTML — both of your select controls are using `id="category"` and that's invalid. An `id` must be unique within a page.
Maybe you mean for both of these to be a "category thing"; in that case it should be `class="category"` (classes should describe what a thing ***is***, not how a thing ***looks***)
Maybe you really want to identify which is which; then you want two *different* ids...  I'll do both -- change them to classes to make the HTML valid and add a unique `id` in case you need to target them exactly.

You also define the CSS class `.epcCatHide6` but you don't *use it* anywhere in your HTML...  I'll wrap your selects in divs and put that class on a div.

This gives...

```
<div class="plain">
    <select name="epcCat[1]" id="cat1" class="formElements category">
        <option value="1">Blah</option>
        <option value="3">Blah Blah</option>
        <option value="4">Blah Blah Blah</option>
        <option value="5">Etc</option>
        <option value="180">Etc Etc</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="epcCatHide6">
    <select name="epcCat[6]" id="cat6" class="formElements category">
        <option value="0">-----</option>
        <option value="181">12</option>
        <option value="182">11</option>
        <option value="183">10</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now, when you pick option 3 from `epcCat[1]` all you have to do is `$(".epcCatHide6").show()` and when you pick something else, to hide it again, just call `$(".epcCatHide6").hide()`

```
$('body').on('change','[name="epcCat[1]"]', function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    if (val == '3') {
        $('.epcCatHide6').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.epcCatHide6').hide();
    }
});
```

Even better, you can use jQuery [`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) which takes a parameter telling it to *either* show or hide -- true -> show and false -> hide.

This makes your handler simpler:

```
$('body').on('change','[name="epcCat[1]"]', function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    $('.epcCatHide6').toggle( val == '3' ); // shows when 3, hides when anything else.
});
```

Here it is all put together...

```js
$('body').on('change','[name="epcCat[1]"]', function() {
    val = $(this).val();
    $('.epcCatHide6').toggle( val == '3' ); // shows when 3, hides when anything else.
});
```

```css
.epcCatHide6 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Pick <em>Blah Blah = 3</em> to show the other select control.
<div class="plain">
    <select name="epcCat[1]" id="cat1" class="formElements category">
        <option value="1">Blah = 1</option>
        <option value="3">Blah Blah = 3</option>
        <option value="4">Blah Blah Blah = 4</option>
        <option value="5">Etc = 5</option>
        <option value="180">Etc Etc = 180</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="epcCatHide6">
    <select name="epcCat[6]" id="cat6" class="formElements category">
        <option value="0">-----</option>
        <option value="181">12</option>
        <option value="182">11</option>
        <option value="183">10</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

— or as [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/6d5fwrq7/) which you can fork and... and... fiddle with.
The [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/6d5fwrq7/1/) includes setting the visibility on page load in case the value of the first select is already `3`.

Comment: Yes the .toggle almost does it. Only problem is that on page load option one is the default and so doesn't get toggled. I can't edit the select boxes because they are ioncube encrypted..

Comment: @Weyboat -- but the CSS makes it already hidden on load; recall there is the rule `.epcCatHide6 {display:none}` (I'm working on a stack snippet to show the whole thing)

Comment: Are yes.. I removed the css styling, I will put it back and see if it works

Comment: Yes that works perfectly.. Wonderful Thank You so Much!

Comment: Slight glitch, when the page is revisited, the epcCatHide6 select box does not show again until epcCat[1] is toggled. is there some way to display epcCatHide6 when it has been previously selected and the page saved?

Comment: @Weyboat - yes there is, when the page loads you can check the value of the first select control and show/hide epcCatHide6 based on that value. Just like the _change_ handler, `$('.epcCatHide6').toggle( val == '3' );` but do it when the document is ready: `$(document).ready(function() { $('.epcCatHide6').toggle( val == '3' ); });` (worth an upvote?)

Comment: @Weyboat -- I've included an updated fiddle that demonstrates the initial check on page load : https://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/6d5fwrq7/1/

Comment: I just needed to change the ID from #cat to #category (see my original post) and this now working perfectly..

Comment: A small bug, if the page is revisted for editing and the epcCat[1] is changed from '3' to some other value, the epcCatHide6 select does not revert to select option '0'.
Can this be overcome?